# Interpretation of the output of sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn to compute precision and recall for a **binary** classification project.

```
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, numpy.asarray(X_features), numpy.asarray(Y_targets), \
                            cv = 5, score_func = metrics.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support )
```

The scoring function I am using is **metrics.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support**.

The partial output is as below:

```
[[[  0.95652174   1.        ]
  [  1.           0.95348837]
  [  0.97777778   0.97619048]
  [ 44.          43.        ], ......]
```

The first row is precision, the second row is recall.
But since it is a binary classification, I wonder which column is for "0" class and which is for "1" class? If it is a multi-class classification, e.g. "0", "1", "2", how does sklearn order the classes in outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using fit() you can get the corresponding classes in the same order through the classes_ property of the classifier model (ie. my_model.classes_).

It is not available in your case so use numpy.unique(Y_targets) => it is the same internal method used so it will be in the same order.

Comment: I tried "clf.classes_" but got "AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute 'classes_'". Maybe this is a special case.

Comment: it is initialized when you use fit() but apparently not when you use cross_val_score. Anyway, you can use the internal method used by scikit and it will be then in the same order: numpy.unique(Y_targets)